# QStateMachine addTransition for signals with params

Tags: qt, qstatemachine

What is the best and short way to inplace addTransition on signal with params (c++/c++11):

```
QCheckBox checkBox;

QStateMachine machine;

QState *s1 = new QState();
QFinalState *s2 = new QFinalState();

s1->addTransition(&checkbox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int state)), s2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that *there is nothing more that has to be done* : the code that I included in the question worked. State transition is triggered by any signal included the signals with parameters.